# Remove part of file path in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, filepath

I am are receiving  an array as a variable

Is an example

```
["/a/b/01_Sources/02_Transferred/06_CPAS/Redbull/from_MediaHouse/Transcripts/MI201711200143.xlsx", "/a/b/01_Sources/02_Transferred/06_CPAS/Redbull/from_MediaHouse/Transcripts/MI201703030110.pdf"]
```

The following statement creates this list:

```
<%= var(file_list_array).map{|file| "<li>#{File.basename(file)}</li>"}.join("\n")%>
```

MI201711200143.xlsx

MI201703030110.pdf

The following statement creates this list

```
<%= var(file_list_array).map{|file| "<li>#{file}</li>"}.join("\n")%>
```

/a/b/01_Sources/02_Transferred/06_CPAS/Redbull/from_MediaHouse/Transcripts/MI201711200143.xlsx

/a/b/01_Sources/02_Transferred/06_CPAS/Redbull/from_MediaHouse/Transcripts/MI201703030110.pdf

**But what I would really like:**

/Redbull/from_MediaHouse/Transcripts/MI201711200143.xlsx

/Redbull/from_MediaHouse/Transcripts/MI201703030110.pdf

What do I need to change to get that ?

Comment: What determines the part of the path you want to keep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your array of file paths in an array you could do.

```
file_paths.map{|path| path.gsub(/.*(\/Redbull\/.*)/, $1) }
```

This will replace each item with whatever is below the "Redbull" directory

Alternatively if you didn't want to preprocess that list you could just put it in your display code, but that will make it less clear as to what you need to send the displaying logic.

```
<%= var(file_list_array).map{|file| "<li>#{file.gsub(/.*(\/Redbull\/.*)/, $1)}</li>"}.join("\n")%>
```

Comment: Nice catch on the second example.  I mixed up the two erb sampless

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
file_list_array[0].split("06_CPAS")[1]
```

assuming you want to split from `"06_CPAS"` . You can pass it as a variable too like this

```
split_str = "06_CPAS"
index = 0
file_list_array[index].split(split_str)[1]
```